# Embedded-Debezium spring boot postgreSQL DB connectivity issue

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I tried connecting postgreSQL with spring boot and embedded debezium, the DB connection is getting established, after the table is locked i get access denied. I am logging in with replication access. Kindly find the below logs.

```
2020-09-15 20:27:00.806  INFO 14784 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.d.c.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask   : user 'loginUser' connected to database 'pgDatabase' on PostgreSQL 12.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit with roles:
    role 'loginUser' [superuser: false, replication: true, inherit: true, create role: false, create db: false, can log in: true]
2020-09-15 20:27:00.813  INFO 14784 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.d.c.p.connection.PostgresConnection    : Obtained valid replication slot ReplicationSlot [active=false, latestFlushedLsn=null, catalogXmin=null]
2020-09-15 20:27:00.813  INFO 14784 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.d.c.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask   : Found previous offset PostgresOffsetContext [sourceInfoSchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source:STRUCT}, sourceInfo=source_info[server='pgServer.com-pgDatabase'db='pgDatabase', lsn=LSN{2/61010900}, txId=14082, timestamp=2020-09-10T01:04:03.660Z, snapshot=FALSE], partition={server=pgServer.com-pgDatabase}, lastSnapshotRecord=true, lastCompletelyProcessedLsn=null, lastCommitLsn=null, transactionContext=TransactionContext [currentTransactionId=null, perTableEventCount={}, totalEventCount=0]]
2020-09-15 20:27:00.814  INFO 14784 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.d.c.p.snapshot.InitialSnapshotter      : Previous snapshot has completed successfully, streaming logical changes from last known position
2020-09-15 20:27:00.871 DEBUG 14784 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2020-09-15 20:27:08.185  INFO 14784 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.d.c.p.c.PostgresReplicationConnection  : Initializing PgOutput logical decoder publication
2020-09-15 20:27:08.243  INFO 14784 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.d.c.p.c.PostgresReplicationConnection  : Creating new publication 'dbz_publication' for plugin 'PGOUTPUT'
2020-09-15 20:27:08.246  INFO 14784 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.d.c.p.c.PostgresReplicationConnection  : Creating Publication with statement 'CREATE PUBLICATION dbz_publication FOR ALL TABLES;'
2020-09-15 20:27:08.765  INFO 14784 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.a.k.c.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore   : Stopped FileOffsetBackingStore
2020-09-15 20:27:09.059 ERROR 14784 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine      : Unable to initialize and start connector's task class 'io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask' with config: {connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector, database.user=loginUser, database.dbname=pgDatabase, offset.storage=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore, database.server.name=pgServer.com-pgDatabase, database.port=5432, plugin.name=pgoutput, table.whitelist=schema.tableName, offset.flush.interval.ms=10000, offset.storage.file.filename=/Users/loginUser/student-offset.dat, database.hostname=pgServer.com, database.password=********, name=student-postgres-connector}

io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnectionException: ERROR: permission denied for database pgDatabase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [permissions](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-permissions) of your role `loginUser`:

> Setting up a PostgreSQL server to run a Debezium connector requires a database user who can perform replications. Replication can be performed only by a database user who has appropriate permissions and only for a configured number of hosts.

Comment: Did it help you?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience one needs (with pgoutput plugin starting from v10.x):

- Enable logical replication on DB instance;
- User belonging to REPLICATION (or rds_replication for AWS RDS - server-less options seems to be broken for years) role;
- Be owner (the user connecting to DB) of all white-listed tables;
- Have USE, SELECT on all white-listed tables and sequences;
- Have access for USE, SELECT on "public" schema (meta data);
- Have permissions to create objects on "public" schema.

Note: the requirement to have rds_admin is not a requirement but simple way to get started if the list above is overhwhelming.